# My x rotation matrix is not working how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, matrix-multiplication

I've been working on this 3D rasterizer implementation in JS for a while and for whatever reason, every time I try and get `x` rotation the actual matrix doesn't work.

I did put it in the orientation that matched how my matrix multiplication function worked so that is not the issue.

If anyone can figure out why this didn't work I'd greatly appreciate it, this has been tough to make because of a lack of resources. Edit: also the perspective divide doesn't work at 1 because dividing by 1 leaves you with the same coordinates.

```
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.setAttribute("id", "myCanvas");
canvas.setAttribute("width", 1000);
canvas.setAttribute("height", 500);
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let element;

let fps = 1000/24;

var theta = 0;

let run = true;
switch (run) {
    case true:
        setInterval(function() {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            //ctx.rect(0, 0, 150, 150);

            theta++;
            var tta = (theta/180)*3.14159;
            
            //point
            function pt(x, y, z) {
                return [x, y, z, 1];
            }
            
            //line drawing function
            function drawL(p, p2) {
                ctx.moveTo(p[0]+(canvas.width*0.5), -p[1]+(canvas.height*0.5));
                ctx.lineTo(p2[0]+(canvas.width*0.5), -p2[1]+(canvas.height*0.5));
            }
            
            //triangle drawer function
            function dt(p, p2, p3) {
                drawL(p, p2);
                drawL(p2, p3);
                drawL(p3, p);
            }

            //matrix multiplication
            function matmul(point, m) {
                var x = point[0]*m[0][0]+point[1]*m[0][1]+point[2]*m[0][2]+point[3]*m[0][3];
                var y = point[0]*m[1][0]+point[1]*m[1][1]+point[2]*m[1][2]+point[3]*m[1][3];
                var z = point[0]*m[2][0]+point[1]*m[2][1]+point[2]*m[2][2]+point[3]*m[2][3];
                var w = point[0]*m[3][0]+point[1]*m[3][1]+point[2]*m[3][2]+point[3]*m[3][3];
            
                switch(true) {
                    case w!=0:
                        x/=w;
                        y/=w;
                        z/=w;
                        break;                
                }
                var POINT = [x, y, z, w];
                return POINT;
            }
            
            //matrix variables for my perspective projection
            var znear = 0.1;
            var zfar = 1000;
            var fov = (90/180)*3.14159;
            var h = canvas.height, w = canvas.width;
            var a = h/w;
    
            var prjM = [[a*(1/Math.tan(fov/2)), 0, 0, 0], [0, 1/Math.tan(fov/2), 0, 0], [0, 0, -(zfar/(zfar-znear)), -((zfar*znear)/(zfar-znear))], [0, 0, 1, 0]];

            var sm = [[300, 0, 0, 0], [0, 150, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]];
            
            function all(p) {
                var sp = matmul(p, sm)
                var np = matmul(sp, prjM);
                return np;
            }

            //front tris
            var tp = pt(0, 0, 0);
            var tp2 = pt(1, 0, 0);
            var tp3 = pt(1, 1, 0);

            var p = all(tp);
            var p2 = all(tp2);
            var p3 = all(tp3);
           
            var tp4 = pt(1, 1, 0);
            var tp5 = pt(0, 1, 0);
            var tp6 = pt(0, 0, 0);

            var p4 = all(tp4);
            var p5 = all(tp5);
            var p6 = all(tp6);

            //back tris
            var tp7 = pt(0, 1, 1.1);
            var tp8 = pt(1, 1, 1.1);
            var tp9 = pt(1, 0, 1.1);

            var p7 = all(tp7);
            var p8 = all(tp8);
            var p9 = all(tp9);
            
            var tp10 = pt(1, 0, 1.1);
            var tp11 = pt(0, 0, 1.1);
            var tp12 = pt(0, 1, 1.1);

            var p10 = all(tp10);
            var p11 = all(tp11);
            var p12 = all(tp12);

            //right side tris
            var tp13 = pt(1, 1, 0);
            var tp14 = pt(1, 0, 0);
            var tp15 = pt(1, 1, 1.1);

            var p13 = all(tp13);
            var p14 = all(tp14);
            var p15 = all(tp15);

            var tp16 = pt(1, 0, 0);
            var tp17 = pt(1, 0, 1.1);
            var tp18 = pt(1, 1, 1.1);

            var p16 = all(tp16);
            var p17 = all(tp17);
            var p18 = all(tp18);

            //left side tris
            var tp19 = pt(0, 1, 0);
            var tp20 = pt(0, 0, 1.1);
            var tp21 = pt(0, 1, 0);

            var p19 = all(tp19);
            var p20 = all(tp20);
            var p21 = all(tp21);

            var tp22 = pt(0, 0, 1.1);
            var tp23 = pt(0, 1, 1.1);
            var tp24 = pt(0, 1, 0);

            var p22 = all(tp22);
            var p23 = all(tp23);
            var p24 = all(tp24);
            
            //top
            var tp25 = pt(0, 1, 0);
            var tp26 = pt(0, 1, 1.1);
            var tp27 = pt(1, 1, 1.1);

            var p25 = all(tp25);
            var p26 = all(tp26);
            var p27 = all(tp27);

            var tp28 = pt(1, 1, 1.1);
            var tp29 = pt(0, 1, 0);
            var tp30 = pt(1, 1, 0);

            var p28 = all(tp28);
            var p29 = all(tp29);
            var p30 = all(tp30);

            //bottom
            var tp31 = pt(0, 0, 0);
            var tp32 = pt(0, 0, 1.1);
            var tp33 = pt(1, 0, 1.1);

            var p31 = all(tp31);
            var p32 = all(tp32);
            var p33 = all(tp33);

            var tp34 = pt(1, 0, 1.1);
            var tp35 = pt(0, 0, 0);
            var tp36 = pt(1, 0, 0);

            var p34 = all(tp34);
            var p35 = all(tp35);
            var p36 = all(tp36);
            
            dt(p, p2, p3);
            dt(p4, p5, p6);
            
            dt(p7, p8, p9);
            dt(p10, p11, p12);
            
            dt(p13, p14, p15);
            dt(p16, p17, p18);
            
            dt(p19, p20, p21);
            dt(p22, p23, p24);

            dt(p25, p26, p27);
            dt(p28, p29, p30);

            dt(p31, p32, p33);
            dt(p34, p35, p36);
            
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();
        }, fps);
        break;
    
}
```